# How to replace parent fragment view with a child fragment's view?

Tags: android, android-fragments

I'm looking for some help in Android studio with replacing a parent fragment's view with the view of a child fragment when a view in the parent fragment is clicked. Thank you in advance for your help.

Right now I have a parent fragment which is a chat list, and a child fragment (the chat screen) that shows up when you click on an element of the chat screen (i.e. a button). The chat list looks like this:

```
<FrameLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    tools:context="com.example.myapplication.ChatListFragment">

    <!-- Empty Container for Fragment to Live in -->
    <FrameLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
        android:id="@+id/fragment_container"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent" />

    <ListView
        android:id="@+id/chatListView"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:background="@color/moonstone">
    </ListView>

</FrameLayout>
```

[image: Chat List Screen]

I have set the onClickListener for the chatListView as follows:

```
_chatListView.setOnItemClickListener(new AdapterView.OnItemClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> adapterView, View view, int i, long l) {


                String chatName = _chatListAdapter.getItem(i).getChatTitle();

                openChatScreen(chatName);
            }
        });
```

And the openChatScreenWindow() looks like this:

```
private void openChatScreen(String chatName)
    {
        _fragmentManager = getChildFragmentManager();

        Log.i(CHAT_LIST_TAG, "starting chat screen fragment");

        FragmentTransaction fragmentTransaction = _fragmentManager.beginTransaction();

        ChatScreenFragment chatScreenFragment = ChatScreenFragment.newInstance(chatName);
        fragmentTransaction.add(R.id.fragment_container, chatScreenFragment);
        fragmentTransaction.addToBackStack(GlobalConstants.OPEN_CHAT_WINDOW_FRAGMENT_STRING + chatName);

        fragmentTransaction.commit();
    }
```

However, when I run this code, the child fragment is obscured, because both the frame layout (the view that the fragment is displayed in) and the chatListView have their widths and heights set to `match_parent` (I figured this out by testing the height and width of the chat list as 200dp, and I was able to see the child fragment behind it).

Is there a simple way to get the fragment to replace the chatListView whenever it is loaded?

For example, is there a way to change this view:

[image: Chat List Screen]

To this one:

[image: Chat Screen]

... when an element in the chat list (the first one) is clicked?

I was thinking of changing the list view's visibility to invisible and visible based on whether the fragment is loaded, but that seems like a headache.

Please let me know what you think, thank you!

Comment: Can you move the chatListView inside the main fragment? And inflate it from there?

Comment: The chatListView is inside the main fragment in the form of a tab layout. The problem is that I need to inflate the ChatScreen from the chatListView

Answer (score 0):

First off most modern way of managing fragments is - [Navigation component](https://developer.android.com/guide/navigation/navigation-getting-started)

According your approach - you are adding child fragment on top of the prev fragment with `fragmentTransaction.add`, you can use `fragmentTransaction.replace instead`

Also, you might want to set child fragment background to solid color - to hide previous fragment, if you use this method - make child's fragment root clickable - to prevent fragments click through.

My recommendation - spend more time on learning Navigation component

Comment: Okay, thank you. I will look into the navigation component, I didn't even realize it existed!